# Webpack not building after npm upgrade

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack, webpack-3, extracttextwebpackplugin

I had a minor issue with my React test scripts and I ended up upgrading my npm with following command

```
npm upgrade -g
```

I think this not only upgraded `npm` ( to 5.3.0) but also `webpack` ( to 3.4.1), `extract-text-webpack-plugin` ( to 3.0.0), and every `npm` package.

Ideally, this should have resolved all issues but I am getting following error 
while using `webpack` to build my code:

---

```
C:\Users\xxx\Google Drive\sites\trip\jsbuild>webpack -d --display-error-details
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:49
                throw new Error("Chunk.entry was removed. Use hasRuntime()");
                ^

Error: Chunk.entry was removed. Use hasRuntime()
    at Chunk.entry (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:49:9)
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\index.js:201:13
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\index.js:200:37)
    at Compilation.applyPlugins0 (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:68:14)
    at Compilation.seal (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:567:8)
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:514:17
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:481:11
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:452:13
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

---

Could not find any solutions on google....
Would be great if someone can point me in right direction...

Answer (score 0):

What version of webpack were you using prior to upgrading it? There are significant configuration differences between webpack 1 and 2/3.

I'd suggest rolling webpack back to the previous version for now. Figure out how to migrate your webpack config file, then migrate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.    Ended up updating few packages and adding one to get it to work.   So now I have webpack ( 3.5.1), npm (5.3.0), extract-text-webpack-plugin( 3.0.0) and tough-cokie........still figuring out why mocha/jsdom test scripts not working.....